# Split Get from Python dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have a dictionary that I can use the get method to extract values from but I need to subset these values. For example

```
dict_of_measures = {k: v for k, v in measures.groupby('Measure')}
```

And I am using get

```
BCS=dict_of_measures.get('BCS')
```

I have several values and wanted to know if I could use a for loop to extract from the dictionary and subset into multiple dataframes per measure using the get method? Is this possible?

```
for measure name in dict_of_measures: 
          get measure name()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dict comprehension-

```
result= []
keys_to_extract = ['key1','key2']
new_dict = {k: bigdict[k] for k in keys_to_extract}
result.append(new_dict) # add dictionary to list. This can then be converted into pandas dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks, which code would you use to convert the new_dict to a pandas dataframe?